# Does Gödel's incompleteness theorem invoke a Law of Excluded Middle contradiction?

Tags: logic, proof-theory, incompleteness, peano-axioms

Does Gödel's incompleteness theorem cause the Law of Non Contradiction to contradict its self?

If so, would this be a considered a conjecture?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please choose your tags with care. What has this to do with `number-theory` or `proof-verification`?

Comment: Why should Gödel's theorem contradict the Law of Excluded Middle?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco from the wiki: "there will always be statements about the natural numbers that are true, but that are unprovable within the system". I can prove the number 2 (counting). And.  "system cannot demonstrate its own consistency" , again I present the #2.  Counting is your first provable science. Godel says 'nope'. Isn't that a contradiction?

Comment: G's Th does **not** says that **every** math statement is unprovable, but oly that (in the context of a specified mathematical formal system) there are unprovable statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not really. Gödel's theorem does not appeal to notion of "truth" of a conjecture *per se* - merely to its provability within a given set of axioms. The "provability" operator can be intuitively understood as $\square_A \psi= A \Rightarrow \psi$, $A$ being the set of axioms: even under the law of excluded middle, it is not guaranteed that $[\lnot(\xi \Rightarrow \psi)] \Rightarrow (\xi \Rightarrow \lnot \psi)$.

Comment: But if math is to be empirical, counting is your first science. Wouldn't the #2 be completely provable. Isn't Godel saying 'not so fast' with counting as empiricle?

Comment: Well, Gödel's theorem does not imply that nothing is provable within any axiomatization of any system, just that in any limited (ie. countable) and consistent axiomatization of any rich enough system there will be some unprovable facts. What exactly do you mean by "complete provability of #2"?

Comment: If math is an abstract representation of our physical universe, I know that I can irrefutable prove that I have 2 (some real number) widgets in my hand. I can have a judge of a court certify it, 3rd party verify, all kind of things outside of math to prove that 2. So ANY set of axioms you choose, better mean my 2 means 2, or you have a quark in your system (some conjecture). From what I can tell, Gödel says that is not inherently provable. It sounds like Gödel is calling my judge a liar. I am addressing "what is proof".

Comment: Ah, I see.
Existence of number 2 is actually provable with Peano axioms: it can be proven that there exists a number that is a consequent of a consequent of 0, equal neither 0 nor the consequent of 0. Furthermore, Peano arithmetic limited to the operation of addition is not affectted by Gödel's theorem, so all the additive properties of 2 can also be proven in a consistent system.

BTW: the assumption that "math is an abstract representation of our physical universe" is a rather strong one and it's not universally accepted: I, for one, am a Platonist.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed information

Answer (score 2):

The fact that, by Gödel's incompleteness theorem,

> "there will always be statements about the natural numbers that are true, but that are unprovable within the system"

does not contradict the Law of Excluded Middle. It means that there is a statement $G$ about natural numbers that is true in the standard model of arithmetic (the one whose domain is the set of natural number $0$, $1$, $2$, $\dots$), but is false in [non-standard models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_model_of_arithmetic) of first-order Peano arithmetic (this is the reason why $G$ is unprovable in first-order Peano arithmetic). Indeed,  according to Gödel's [completeness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem) for first-order logic, a statement is provable in a system if and only if it is true in *every* model of such a system: this not the case for the statement $G$ and Peano arithmetic as  system.

Comment: What if we have an incosistent set of axioms? Then we can have both A and not A to be true.